# Использование бинарных файлов в программе C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, macos, binary-file

Есть определенный бинарный файл, который я хочу вызывать с помощью функции `system`. Я пробовал сделать вот так: `system("bzip2/bzip2 -d 1.bz2");`, но, конечно, ничего не получилось, ведь программа принимала этот путь от своего собственного бинарного файла (а в функции я указал от файла исходного кода). Каким образом мне сослаться на этот бинарный файл?

Comment: Указывайте путь относительно бинарного файла или лучше используйте абсолютный путь.

Comment: Полезная команда : > which bzip2   =>  
/usr/bin/bzip2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить проблему с путями к файлу придется одним из способов:

1. Держать требуемый файл рядом с бинарём вашей программы;
2. Использовать абсолютный путь;
3. Заранее настроить переменные среды вашей целевой ОС.

Дополнительно, вам может помочь Qt:

1. Можете получить текущий путь при помощи `QDir::currentPath()`;
2. Вместо `int system(const char *str)` использовать класс `QProcess`

Вот пример использования в случае, если путь к *bzip2* добавлен в переменную окружения `PATH`, а целевой архив расположен рядом с программой в каталоге `archives`:

```
QString comand = QString("bzip2 -d ") + QDir::currentPath() + 
QString("/archives/1.bz2");
QProcess unarchiveProcess;
unarchiveProcess.start(comand);
if(!unarchiveProcess.waitForStarted(500)){
    qDebug() << "start failed";
}
if(!unarchiveProcess.waitForFinished(5000)){
    qDebug() << "stop failed";
    unarchiveProcess.close();
    unarchiveProcess.waitForFinished();
    unarchiveProcess.Disconnection();
}
```

**update**

1. Вы можете собрать библиотеку `libbzip2` из исходного кода и использовать ее напрямую из вашей программы. [Вот](http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html) актуальная версия.
2. Использовать boost. [Вот](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/bzip2.html) пример кода.